# Exception while using threading library in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, multithreading

A newbie in Django here,

I have been experiencing some issues while using basic threading in Django

Here is my script

```
from threading import Thread


def run_threads(msg1, msg2):
    class Hello(Thread):
        def run(self):
            for i in range(500):
                print(msg1)

    class Hi(Thread):
        def run(self):
            for i in range(500):
                print(msg2)

    t1 = Hello()
    t2 = Hi()
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    print("Here")
```

But upon running, it is giving me following error

```
somethingException in thread Exception in threading.excepthook:Exception ignored in thread started byException ignored in sys.unraisablehookis cookingException in thread Exception in threading.excepthook:E
xception ignored in thread started byException ignored in sys.unraisablehookHere
```

But if I run it in Python3 console without Django, it works alright. Any help would be highly appreciated

Information on my system:

Python: `3.8`

Django: `(3, 1, 4, 'final', 0)`

Comment: First thing first django is the thread I mean to say django it self run on threads and if you require threading in django then this might help you https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: @Bhupeshlad on my roadmap, I will be using celery in near future but still I need to run threads inside a function, I need to scrap and bulk import inside a single celery task.

Comment: django runs on synchronous thread so theres no way you can run any thread there directly there are many parameters like cookies and sessions in django that have to consider in django you cant just directly call thread there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon research, I decided to go for celery integration with my app and run the tasks async which work as threads for me in Django. Hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sync_to_async method or celery library
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html